# How to find the computer name of a Basic Azure Website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an Azure Website in `Basic` web plan hosting mode. I need the computer name of this Azure Website for a third party license to run correctly.

I cannot find the computer name in the Azure Management Portal.

It is my understanding with the Azure Website web plan hosting modes `Free` and `Standard` that I am on a shared IIS setup with many other websites.

But when I switched to basic I have the option to run 32Bit or 64Bit and I can scale instance size and instanced count.

So it is possible, with my Azure Website in Basic hosting mode, that I have my own virtual machine with my own computer name. But I am not sure of that.

**What is the infrastructure setup for a Basic Azure Website? Is it possible the website is running on a unique computer name, a computer name I can discover, to use in my third party license?**

Comment: You can find this information out via `Kudu`.  Just navigate to `your-website.scm.azurewebsites.net`.  Via the console, you can run `hostname` and find this information out.  However, it is likely that your hostname will change when updates are applied to the Azure environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I was able to use System.Environment.MachineName to supply the valid values for my third party license.

So, in my Global.asax code behind:

```
ThirdPartyDll._LicenseKey = "xxxxxxx" + "|" + System.Environment.MachineName
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the specific web app, follow this path to reach command prompt:

Development Tools > Console

OR

Development Tools > Advanced Tools > Go > Debug Console > CMD

Once on cmd prompt, type hostname and hit enter.